# Incrementing a field in JSON from angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, mongoose

I have a schema that includes a field like so: `flagCount  : Number`.

I am trying to increment the count by 1 when the user clicks a button (the `reportListing` button). The button is inside a HTML page and looks like:

```
  <img class="flagIcon" id="flag" src="../../../images/red_flag_icon.jpg" background-color=transparent ng-hide="hide" ng-click="reportListing()"/>
```

Relevant part of the controller:

```
app.controller('ListingController', function ($scope, $location, $http) {

    $scope.hide = false;
    $scope.reportListing = function() {
        $http.get("/api/listing/:street/:buildingNumber/:apartmentNumber").success(function (apartment){
            //var count = apartment.flagCount;
            sweetAlert("Thank you!", "This listing has been reported", "success");
            $scope.hide = true;
        });
    };
```

I have tried several ways but failed as I can't access the `flagCount` to update it (is it only possible through the back-end (Node)) ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you meant - can you be more specific as to what you mean by "increment the count by 1"? Also, it might be helpful if you could include a log? Specifically - try logging `apartment` on success? (inject $log service and `$log.debug("Returned obejct: ", apartment);`

Comment: @CodeApprentice I meant it as literally as possible: If count==1 I want it to be count==2 after the user clicks the button.... And ofcourse I want it to be saved in the database (in the JSON).

Comment: Okay cool - so this is the right API for incrementing the count? `/api/listing/:street/:buildingNumber/:apartmentNumber`

Comment: Also please include a log of the returned object `apartment` - maybe we can see what's going on. :)

Comment: No, that's what I'm asking really... This API fetches a JSON of an apartment, which *has* a field called flagCount which I would  like to increment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97750/discussion-between-idos-and-code-apprentice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node will have to send a response object with the flagCount property if you want to use it in the frontend. If the flagCount is just getting saved in a database you do not need to use a get request for it.

You could use a post request instead. A post request is useful to change database info.

Node can respond with the flagCount if you need it on the frontend.

If you do need the flagCount then check the node response object to see if it is sending it. If the flagCount is used in the browser than you could also save it and retrieve it in an angular service.

Comment: Is it good practice to define POST in the api (in routes.js) and call it from the controller?

Comment: Use an angular service to make requests. Inject the service into the controllers. The controller can pass any parameters. Otherwise each controller has to have the posting code repeated.
On the node side, yes routes.js is a good place to set up the end point for the request. It's a good idea to put the handlers in a different file or at least outside of the route end point so the same functions can be used on multiple routes. For instance a function to save something to a database may be able to respond to many different route requests.